# Jquery - How to read Variable from Another Function

Tags: jquery

In JQuery, I have this function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {
            var air_id =  $(this).val();
            var a = $(this).parent();
            var op = "";
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{{ route('get.employeeleavecounts.all') }}',
                data: { 'id': air_id },
                dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
                // console.log("Its Change !");
                success: function(data) {      
                    var holidayDays =  data.nationalholidays;   
                    console.log(data.nationalholidays);
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

holiday_days comes like this in the console:

```
0:
holiday_date: "2020-08-25 00:00:00"
__proto__: Object
1:
holiday_date: "2020-08-26 00:00:00"
__proto__: Object
2: {holiday_date: "2020-09-25 00:00:00"}
3: {holiday_date: "2020-11-30 00:00:00"}

__proto__: Array(0)
```

I have another javascript function that is shown below.

How can I call holidayDays inside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#leave_days").on('keyup blur', function (e) {
            var periodval=parseInt($("#leave_days").val());          

          });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a global variable :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nationalholidays = [];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change', '#leave_type', function() {
            var air_id =  $(this).val();
            var a = $(this).parent();
            var op = "";
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{{ route('get.employeeleavecounts.all') }}',
                data: { 'id': air_id },
                dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
                // console.log("Its Change !");
                success: function(data) {      
                    var holidayDays =  data.nationalholidays;   
                    console.log(data.nationalholidays);
                    nationalholidays = data.nationalholidays;
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And use it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#leave_days").on('keyup blur', function (e) {
        var periodval=parseInt($("#leave_days").val());          
        console.log(nationalholidays);
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way you can help me out on:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64747124/jquery-ui-datepicker-national-holidays-count